# Convert Dictionary to JSON in Swift shows many "\\"

Tags: json, swift

I am trying to create a JSON from my App & POST it to my server. The Below code works fine until i changed my syntax to Swift 2.

Now I can't figure out. where the problem comes from ?

```
// Dictionary

    jsonDic = ["REG_ID": Regid!, "COURSE_ID": CourseID, "QUESTION_ID": sqid, "EXAM_CHAPTER_ID": ECID[index], "EXAM_RESULT_ID": ID, "USER_ANSWER": userans, "USER_TIMING": usertime, "REVIEWED": MFR, "RIGHT_ANSWER": right]

// Dictionary to JSON

     let theJSONData = try? NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(
                    jsonDic ,
                    options: NSJSONWritingOptions(rawValue: 0))
                let theJSONText = NSString(data: theJSONData!,
                    encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)
                JSONArray.append(theJSONText! as String)
                print(JSONArray)
```

**OUTPUT**

```
["{\"USER_ANSWER\":\"1188\",\"QUESTION_ID\":\"391\",\"REG_ID\":\"2\",\"COURSE_ID\":\"111\",\"EXAM_RESULT_ID\":\"000\",\"USER_TIMING\":\"33\",\"REVIEWED\":\"\",\"RIGHT_ANSWER\":\"\",\"EXAM_CHAPTER_ID\":\"17\"}",
"{\"USER_ANSWER\":\"1195\",\"QUESTION_ID\":\"395\",\"REG_ID\":\"2\",\"COURSE_ID\":\"111\",\"EXAM_RESULT_ID\":\"000\",\"USER_TIMING\":\"2\",\"REVIEWED\":\"\",\"RIGHT_ANSWER\":\"Y\",\"EXAM_CHAPTER_ID\":\"17\"}",
"{\"USER_ANSWER\":\"1157\",\"QUESTION_ID\":\"380\",\"REG_ID\":\"2\",\"COURSE_ID\":\"111\",\"EXAM_RESULT_ID\":\"000\",\"USER_TIMING\":\"2\",\"REVIEWED\":\"\",\"RIGHT_ANSWER\":\"\",\"EXAM_CHAPTER_ID\":\"17\"}",
"{\"USER_ANSWER\":\"1180\",\"QUESTION_ID\":\"387\",\"REG_ID\":\"2\",\"COURSE_ID\":\"111\",\"EXAM_RESULT_ID\":\"000\",\"USER_TIMING\":\"1\",\"REVIEWED\":\"\",\"RIGHT_ANSWER\":\"Y\",\"EXAM_CHAPTER_ID\":\"17\"}",
"{\"USER_ANSWER\":\"1217\",\"QUESTION_ID\":\"400\",\"REG_ID\":\"2\",\"COURSE_ID\":\"111\",\"EXAM_RESULT_ID\":\"000\",\"USER_TIMING\":\"2\",\"REVIEWED\":\"\",\"RIGHT_ANSWER\":\"\",\"EXAM_CHAPTER_ID\":\"17\"}",
"{\"USER_ANSWER\":\"\",\"QUESTION_ID\":\"401\",\"REG_ID\":\"2\",\"COURSE_ID\":\"111\",\"EXAM_RESULT_ID\":\"000\",\"USER_TIMING\":\"0\",\"REVIEWED\":\"\",\"RIGHT_ANSWER\":\"\",\"EXAM_CHAPTER_ID\":\"17\"}",
"{\"USER_ANSWER\":\"\",\"QUESTION_ID\":\"383\",\"REG_ID\":\"2\",\"COURSE_ID\":\"111\",\"EXAM_RESULT_ID\":\"000\",\"USER_TIMING\":\"0\",\"REVIEWED\":\"\",\"RIGHT_ANSWER\":\"\",\"EXAM_CHAPTER_ID\":\"17\"}",
"{\"USER_ANSWER\":\"\",\"QUESTION_ID\":\"396\",\"REG_ID\":\"2\",\"COURSE_ID\":\"111\",\"EXAM_RESULT_ID\":\"000\",\"USER_TIMING\":\"0\",\"REVIEWED\":\"\",\"RIGHT_ANSWER\":\"\",\"EXAM_CHAPTER_ID\":\"17\"}",
"{\"USER_ANSWER\":\"\",\"QUESTION_ID\":\"398\",\"REG_ID\":\"2\",\"COURSE_ID\":\"111\",\"EXAM_RESULT_ID\":\"000\",\"USER_TIMING\":\"0\",\"REVIEWED\":\"\",\"RIGHT_ANSWER\":\"\",\"EXAM_CHAPTER_ID\":\"17\"}",
"{\"USER_ANSWER\":\"\",\"QUESTION_ID\":\"382\",\"REG_ID\":\"2\",\"COURSE_ID\":\"111\",\"EXAM_RESULT_ID\":\"000\",\"USER_TIMING\":\"0\",\"REVIEWED\":\"\",\"RIGHT_ANSWER\":\"\",\"EXAM_CHAPTER_ID\":\"17\"}"]
```

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**

```
[{"USER_TIMING":"4","COURSE_ID":"93","USER_ANSWER":"4726","EXAM_RESULT_ID":"901","REG_ID":"1","QUESTION_ID":"1378","RIGHT_ANSWER":"","EXAM_CHAPTER_ID":"35","REVIEWED":""},
    {"USER_TIMING":"2","COURSE_ID":"93","USER_ANSWER":"50856","EXAM_RESULT_ID":"901","REG_ID":"1","QUESTION_ID":"13491","RIGHT_ANSWER":"","EXAM_CHAPTER_ID":"35","REVIEWED":""},
    {"USER_TIMING":"2","COURSE_ID":"93","USER_ANSWER":"50882","EXAM_RESULT_ID":"901","REG_ID":"1","QUESTION_ID":"13497","RIGHT_ANSWER":"","EXAM_CHAPTER_ID":"35","REVIEWED":""},
    {"USER_TIMING":"2","COURSE_ID":"93","USER_ANSWER":"4712","EXAM_RESULT_ID":"901","REG_ID":"1","QUESTION_ID":"1375","RIGHT_ANSWER":"Y","EXAM_CHAPTER_ID":"35","REVIEWED":""},
    {"USER_TIMING":"4","COURSE_ID":"93","USER_ANSWER":"50832","EXAM_RESULT_ID":"901","REG_ID":"1","QUESTION_ID":"13482","RIGHT_ANSWER":"","EXAM_CHAPTER_ID":"35","REVIEWED":""},
    {"USER_TIMING":"3","COURSE_ID":"93","USER_ANSWER":"50876","EXAM_RESULT_ID":"901","REG_ID":"1","QUESTION_ID":"13496","RIGHT_ANSWER":"","EXAM_CHAPTER_ID":"35","REVIEWED":""},
    {"USER_TIMING":"4","COURSE_ID":"93","USER_ANSWER":"4686","EXAM_RESULT_ID":"901","REG_ID":"1","QUESTION_ID":"1368","RIGHT_ANSWER":"","EXAM_CHAPTER_ID":"35","REVIEWED":"Y"},
    {"USER_TIMING":"4","COURSE_ID":"93","USER_ANSWER":"4707","EXAM_RESULT_ID":"901","REG_ID":"1","QUESTION_ID":"1373","RIGHT_ANSWER":"","EXAM_CHAPTER_ID":"35","REVIEWED":"Y"},
    {"USER_TIMING":"0","COURSE_ID":"93","USER_ANSWER":"","EXAM_RESULT_ID":"901","REG_ID":"1","QUESTION_ID":"1367","RIGHT_ANSWER":"","EXAM_CHAPTER_ID":"35","REVIEWED":""},
    {"USER_TIMING":"0","COURSE_ID":"93","USER_ANSWER":"","EXAM_RESULT_ID":"901","REG_ID":"1","QUESTION_ID":"1369","RIGHT_ANSWER":"","EXAM_CHAPTER_ID":"35","REVIEWED":""}]
```

Comment: What is your `JSONArray`? The `String` does not contain the `append` a string method. @EricD. I just try to print the `theJSONText` string, it does not contain any `\\` character (the `\\` character is removed auto when *print*. Maybe there is a problem with the `JSONArray` variable.

Comment: I ask @user5184878 about his `JSONArray` variable. The part after your name is for you, @Eric D.

Comment: First of all, I guess `JSONArray` is a `String`, but it's not (because String does not have a method to append another string). It can be a json variable type.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92028/discussion-between-t4nhpt-and-eric-d).

Comment: @t4nhpt But why do you say JSONArray is a String? It makes no sense. OP just didn't post the JSONArray declaration but obviously it's an array where OP wants to store their JSON strings.

Answer (score 0):

As Eric suggested, this is what's expected to happen. It's called [escape character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character).

Many languages including Swift use `\` to mark characters that need to be escaped. And if you do want to represent `\`, you'll have to use `\\` to avoiding confusion.

Comment: How can i print it in my console without those Escape sequences "/"

Comment: I don't think that `NSJSONSerialization` provides something like `prettyprint`. You can use [SwiftyJSON](https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON). It's more elegant and robust. Besides, it can do pretty-printing